# Comparisons with loop in python

Tags: python, loops, comparison

I have a problem:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
a= 3
if a==[item for item in list]:
    print(sth)
```

why the program never print?
thanks...

Comment: DO NOT name your variable as list,it internally stands for the type of List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing an integer to a list, which will never return True as they are different types.  Note that `[item for item in list]` is exactly the same as just saying `list`.

You're probably wondering if `3` is in the list; so you can do:

```
if a in list:
    print(sth)
```

Or even:

```
if any(a == item for item in list):
    print(sth)
```

(Although you really should just use the first option. I only put the second option in as it looks similar to your example :p)

---

As a side note, you shouldn't be naming lists `list`, or dictionaries `dict`, as they are built-in types already, and you're just overriding them :p.

Comment: thanks buddy, im quite stupid now after whole day studying programming. also thank you for replying so fast.